# Program fails to move file

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm trying to move file from one place to another directory...So my program will read Log_Deleter, use parameters given in each line to delete the file. 
When I execute the file, it seems like it runs fine (no errors) but non of the files are moved... I'm not sure why it's not moving the file nor display any error...
Can someone please identify the error?

my attempt:

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read -r line ; do
    v=$line
    set -- $v
    cd /
    $(find "$1" -type f -name "$2" -mtime +"$3" -exec mv {} "$4" \;)
done < Log_Deleter.txt
```

Log_Deleter.txt

```
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvSIT1/logs/Server1 'SystemOut_*' 5 /backup/Abackuptest1
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvSIT1/logs/Server2 'SystemOut_*' 5 /backup/Abackuptest2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure why you have `$(find ...)` - that will capture the output of `find` and attempt to parse and execute it as a command, which may not be a problem if there isn't any output, but it doesn't serve a purpose that I can see, either. Try adding `set -x` to your script and examine the trace output to identify what's going wrong...

Comment: Rather than using set and referencing `$1`, `$2`, etc, it would be clearer to do `while read -r path name mtime dest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find is looking for files that have a literal `'` in the name.  You need to remove the single quotes from `$2` before invoking find.  Try:

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read -r path name mtime dest ; do
    name=$( echo $name | tr -d "'" )
    find "$path" -type f -name "$name" -mtime +"$mtime" -exec mv {} "$dest" \;
done < Log_Deleter.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to match a file whose name actually has the single quotes in it.

Barring other problems, I think your script will probably work once you take the quotes out of Log_Deleter.txt.

The quotes are only meaningful when the shell is parsing command input. This is not what the `read` builtin does. And even when reading command input, once the quotes get into a variable they stay there forever unless reread at the shells CLI layer via `eval.`

The shell is not exactly a macro processor. It's a complicated hybrid that a little bit CLI, a little bit programming language, and a little bit macro processor.

And, speaking of eval, it's not necessary to wrap the `find` in an eval-like construct. Simplify your script to run `find` directly and you will find it easier to debug and understand.